# Capture URL of webpage containing Live Agent chat button

Tags: javascript, liveagent

We are implementing Live Agent with a pre-chat form to capture and display information from the customer.  The pre-chat form works great but we also want capture the URL the customer was on when they clicked the chat button.

I added some JavaScript to pass in this detail from the webpage.

`liveagent.addCustomDetail('URL', window.location.href);`

This works fine from a test HTML page on my desktop, but when we put the code on our testing website the URL doesn't get passed through.

On the webpage the code is in the `<body>` tag and looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
    window._laq.push(function(){
        liveagent.showWhenOnline('573XXXXXXXXXXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_573XXXXXXXXXXXX'));
        liveagent.showWhenOffline('573XXXXXXXXXXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_573XXXXXXXXXXXX'));
    });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c2cs-chi.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/37.0/deployment.js'></script>

<script>
    // liveagent.addCustomDetail('URL', window.location.href); Doesn't work either
    window.onload=liveagent.addCustomDetail('URL', window.location.href);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://d.la3-c2cs-chi.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572XXXXXXXXXXXX', '00DXXXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

I'm not JavaScript wiz so I'm not sure if/how much placement matters.

Also using FireFox firebug I see this error when I refresh the page

> ReferenceError: liveagent is not defined

I suspect this is caused by the `addCustomDetail` function but I'm not sure exactly how to find exactly where it is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve my problem with the following bit of JavaScript code.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener
    (
        'DOMContentLoaded',
        function(event)
        {
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('URL', window.location.href);
        }
    );
</script>
```

That captured the URL and passed it